# Qt: deadlocked QMessageBox doesn't appear at signal processing

Tags: qt

**I've added UPD in the end.**

## What i want to do

I have a main GUI thread executing this:

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow; // an engine thread is started here
    mainWindow.show();
    app.exec(); // here the GUI thread enters the event processing loop
}
```

I connect a signal and a slot to handle notifications in GUI thread (*this* is MainWindow) with BlockingQueuedConnection type:

```
connect(&warningSignalEmitter, SIGNAL(popuped(QString)),
    this, SLOT(onPopupWarning(QString)), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
```

If a signal is emitted, the GUI thread shows a MessageBox:

```
void MainWindow::onPopupWarning(QString message)
{
    QMessageBox::warning(nullptr, "Warning", message);
}
```

I have an engine thread creating OpenGL context and executing a rendering loop.
QOpenGLDebugLogger is initialized in this thread with this code:

```
logger = new QOpenGLDebugLogger();
logger->initialize();

connect(logger, SIGNAL(messageLogged(QOpenGLDebugMessage)),
    this, SLOT(glDebugMessageLogged(QOpenGLDebugMessage)),
    Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection);

logger->startLogging(QOpenGLDebugLogger::LoggingMode::SynchronousLogging);
```

The connection type is DirectConnection, so if an error occures when the engine thread calls OpenGL function, the engine thread enters the slot, which is:

```
void Engine::glDebugMessageLogged(const QOpenGLDebugMessage &debugMessage)
{
    emit warningSignalEmitter.popuped(debugMessage.message());
}
```

The engine thread is locked here until the GUI thread has exited MainWindow::onPopupWarning.

So i want see a Message Box if an error has occured in OpenGL function call.

## My problem

If i just emit a signal with *emit warningSignalEmitter.popuped(debugMessage.message())* somewhere in engine code everything works fine, i see a MessageBox, the engine thread is locked at signal emitting, and the GUI thread is locked in onPopupWarning slot until i have clicked OK on the message box.

While the message box is being showed i see this normal stack trace.

[image]

**BUT** if an error occures in OpenGL function call, the engine thread successfully enteres glDebugMessageLogged slot (because of direct connection) and does signal emitting. After that it is locked as expected. The GUI thread enteres the onPopupWarning slot, but when it calls QMessageBox::warning, **the Message Box doesn't appear**, the GUI thread has being locked at this call, and i can't click OK and continue execution.

And I see this unusual stack trace at this deadlock.

[image]

What may it be?

## UPD

I've reported about this issue, now i suppose this is a bug. You can download source code demonstrating the issue here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69780

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I've reported about this issue, now i suppose this is a bug. You can download source code demonstrating the issue here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69780